# ubuntu 12.04 into docker "service mysql start"

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, docker

I need ubuntu 12.04 with developing web-services running (sshd, apache2.2, php5.3, mysql-server). I have ubuntu 14.04, i installed docker.

Then i started container:

```
docker run -t -i ubuntu:12.04 /bin/bash
```

Then:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y mysql-server
```

After that: service mysql start, service mysql status is not working. If i am running container with 14.04 ubuntu, it works well. The same issue is with sshd server.

service apache2 status, service apache2 stop, service apache2 start works well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no init process running inside the container. Therefore the runelevel can't be determined.
If there is an unknown runlevel, upstart can not start mysql. ... see /etc/init/mysql.conf

```
...
start on runlevel [2345]
...
```

If you try to check the runlevel:

```
$ runlevel
unknown
```

... you see it is unknown.

In Docker it is the common way to start the application in foreground.

```
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe
```

If you want to start more than one application, you can use supervisord.

http://supervisord.org/

https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/

Additional i've found a Dockerfile, which starts a init inside a ubuntu:12.04 docker container. Really nice work:

https://github.com/tianon/dockerfiles/blob/master/sbin-init/ubuntu/upstart/12.04/Dockerfile