# docker interactive mode exits after ENTRYPOINT

Tags: docker

Given the following Dockerfile:

```
From python:2.7-wheezy
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade --assume-yes
RUN apt-get install mysql-server --assume-yes
ENTRYPOINT service mysql start
```

When I run the docker, it exits immediately after starting mysql server:

```
Jamess-iMac:docker-python-test jameslin$ docker run -i -t 9618f71f65e4 /bin/bash
[ ok ] Starting MySQL database server: mysqld ..
[info] Checking for tables which need an upgrade, are corrupt or were 
not closed cleanly..
Jamess-iMac:docker-python-test jameslin$
```

How do I make it automatically start up mysql but stays in interactive mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ubuntu 12.04 into docker “service mysql start”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27154567/ubuntu-12-04-into-docker-service-mysql-start)

If you read above thread you can see that `Docker` doesn't have any **runlevel** so mysql doesn't know when it should start.

You can run two container and create a nework between them. One for **mysql** and another for **pythonapp**. Here is how you can create a network between two container

```
docker network create <network_name>
```

Start the container attaching the container to new network using `--net=<network_name>`

```
docker run -d --net=anetwork --name=mysql -e MYSQL_USER=ROOT -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes mysql

docker run --net=anetwork --name=pythonapp -it python:2.7-wheezy bash
```

[image]

I think you are confused between `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`. The key point to understand is that an `ENTRYPOINT` will always be run when the image is started, even if a command is supplied to the **docker run** invocation. If you try to supply a command, it will add that as an argument to the `ENTRYPOINT`, replacing the default defined in the CMD instruction. You can only override the `ENTRYPOINT` if you explicitly pass in an `--entrypoint` flag to the **docker run** command.

This means that running the image with a `/bin/bash` command will not give you a shell; rather it will supply `/bin/bash` as an argument to the **`service mysql start`**.

[Network between container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35184695/5065092)
[ubuntu 12.04 into docker “service mysql start”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27154567/ubuntu-12-04-into-docker-service-mysql-start)

[Difference Between CMD and ENTRYPOINT in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 3):

Your `ENTRYPOINT` / `CMD` directive needs to be a long running command. `service mysql start` is not a continuous command as it runs, in Ubuntu, the service itself and then the command exits.

To make this simple - if you're just trying to run a mysql container you can run `docker run mysql`. If you absolutely need to run a one-off mysql container you can piggy-back off of the way that the default mysql container starts here: [MySql Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/9f95658f528699d2c2017ca42ad163a9d5c5e7c1/5.7/Dockerfile) - `CMD ["mysqld"]` - which should be similar to what you see as the actual start command in `/etc/init.d/mysql`

Comment: but why is it ignoring it's an interactive mode?

Comment: Because you are running off of an entrypoint command that runs and stops.

Comment: so are you saying entrypoint doesn't work well with interactive mode?

Comment: I am not. Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile. In a poor attempt to summarize, a `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` command will run that command and exit. So if your entrypoint is `ENTRYPOINT ls -l /usr/bin` and you run an interactive container you will get an output of your `/usr/bin` folder and a hard exit. For the same reason, you are getting a hard exit from `service mysql start` - this command runs and exits while Mysql runs in the background. Docker `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` commands need to be persistent.

Comment: `mysqld`, on the other hand, runs the service in the foreground and persists, so it never exists until failure, thus keeping your container alive.